# What is the name of the audio that plays when the gray king appears in K-Project?

Tags: music, k-project

I've done a bit of digging but I can't find the track anywhere. It's in episode 7 of return of the kings (the second season). I'd like the title of the track and if possible a link to download it. I really enjoy it's melody and would like to listen to it more often.

Does anyone know who made it or where I can find it?

Comment: It is called, "K vs K" (And, by the way, it is the Silver King, not the gray king)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I found that the track is called `K vs K` from the OST a link to the track here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWjCr2bx9XU